# Can't add minimize button to QDialog under linux

Tags: c++, qt, qdialog

I'm trying to add a minimize button to my QDialog using this code in the constructor:

```
Qt::WindowFlags flags = windowFlags();
flags |= Qt::WindowMinMaxButtonsHint;
setWindowFlags(flags);
```

It's working on Windows but not on Linux.

Comment: This is window manager dependent on Linux.

Comment: Can I do anything from within Qt then? I've tried with QMainWindow, and it has no problem with the minimize button.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its a late answer but could be useful to others, I had the same problem and fixed like so:

```
Qt::WindowFlags flags = Qt::Window | Qt::WindowSystemMenuHint
                            | Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint
                            | Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint;
this->setWindowFlags(flags);
```

inside the overridden dialog constructor.

Comment: In the end I switched the project from QDialog to QMainWindow, which solved my problem, but still, thank you for the answer.