# Enable maximize button in QWizard

Tags: c++, qt, qdialog

I have a Windows application that is built on QWizard (which inherits from QDialog). It must have a working maximization button.

By default maximization button is not even visible. i have set it to show, using:

```
auto flags = windowFlags();
flags ^= Qt::WindowContextHelpButtonHint;
flags |= Qt::WindowMinMaxButtonsHint;
setWindowFlags(flags);
```

However, it shows up disabled (grayed out, non-responding).

How can i enable it?

Comment: QWizard inherits from QDialog, this problem is general for all QDialogs. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699808/cant-add-minimize-button-to-qdialog-under-linux, I had asked a similar question before.

Comment: As you can see from the code snippet, i am aware of that solution. I can only repeat that it doesn't do what i need: with those flags set maximize button is displayed, but not enabled.

Comment: You are right, i should have been more clear in question.

Comment: Have you tried to call `setSizeGripEnabled(true)`?  I mean: if it has a size-grip, it may be resized - which in turn means it should be maximizable...

Comment: The window has size grip and is resizeable. However, maximize buttin is disabled.
For an experiment,  i tried whowing the window maximized. The button is still disabled (and does not change to "restore size" button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you'll get better results creating your own dialog, but if you really wanna do it, one way is use window styles (Windows only, not cross-plataform).

Wizard class example:

```
class wizard : public QWizard
{
public:
    wizard() {}
    ~wizard() {}

protected:
    bool event(QEvent *event)
    {
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN /*Make this code Windows OS only*/
        if (event->type() == QEvent::WinIdChange)
        {
            HWND hwnd = (HWND)winId();
            LONG lStyle = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE);
            lStyle |= (WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX); /*Enable minimize and maximize*/
            SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, lStyle);
        }
#endif

        return QWizard::event(event);
    }
};
```

Comment: I was able to throw a wizard together quickly using qwizard; however the price i am paying for it is pain and frustration of being unable to (for example)change position of a page subtitle

Answer (score 7):

This works for me:

```
setWindowFlags(windowFlags() | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint |
                               Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint |
                               Qt::WindowMaximizeButtonHint |
                               Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint);
```

According to the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum), you have to use the `Qt::CustomizeWindowHint` to be able to change the individual hints on the min/max buttons.

Answer (score 5):

Someone [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/17593-QDialog-with-Close-Maximize-and-Context-Help-Buttons) says this solved his problem:

`setWindowFlags(Qt::Window);`

Comment: With QWizard i do get minimize and maximize button with this flag, however maximizing button is still disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I have this:

```
QWizard *wizard = new QWizard(this, Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::WindowMaximizeButtonHint | Qt::Window);
wizard->setSizeGripEnabled(true);
```

Running Windows 10 on my dev-box, Qt 5.5.1, working for me.

One of my pages is a big QTableWidget that ends up being like an Excel sheet of some sorts (a big page to verify and edit-in-place a lot of data). Making the window resizable and let the user maximize it if they want makes it much easier to work with, instead of having to constantly scroll in a small dialog.

Normally you would say: If you need such a big window, it probably shouldn't be in a QWizard. But in this case it's really the middle of a workflow thing. A big 'verify, edit-if-needed and continue' page so it would be weird to stop the QWizard before and then having to start another one after or something.